# DoE: Why so many center points for Response Surface design in Minitab?

Tags: experiment-design, minitab, response-surface-methodology

I'm finding what seems like an absurd number of default center points with the following Response Surface DoE setup in Minitab. Can someone please help me understand why they're needed and if I can reduce the number of center points without losing too much information:

Minitab DoE:
Response Surface,
Central Composite,
2 Continuous Factors, 1 continuous response, 1 Binary Response,
Full Resolution, Blocked = 14 data points with no replicates.

These data points are distributed as:
4 cube points (all different)
4 axial points (all different)
6 center points (all the same point?)

For 2 continuous factors, the center point for both cube and axial are the same so I would've expected just 1 center point before adding replicates. Even if I keep a center point for both cube and axial arrangements that would just be two points. Why does it default to 6?

Comment: This was as close as I got to answering my own question: